# Problem playing mov file in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

(Im using this with Cocos2d)

This works perfectly for an mp4 video

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro_iphone" ofType:@"mp4"]];

mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]
[mpc setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
mpc.shouldAutoplay = YES;
mpc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
mpc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);

[mpc setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
[mpc setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
[mpc setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:mpc.view];

[mpc play];
```

But if I try and change it to a .mov file, nothing happens!? There is no error, so its picking up the file, but theres no play back and no `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was the codec the .mov was created with, was not iPhone compatible.