# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't play video

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm using this code to try and play a video. However the video is never played, the call back is never made to say it's finished. I can't see anything that I'm missing or have where it shouldn't be. I've checked the path and that's fine. The video playback view does appear. It just doesn't play at that point.

Any suggestions?

```
NSURL *movieURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IntroMovie" withExtension:@"mov"];

NSLog(@"%@", movieURL);

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

[moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: are you using ARC or non-ARC?

Comment: I'm using ARC and targeting iOS 7

Comment: see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493860/problem-playing-mov-file-in-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: This isn't an issue with the video file itself as far as I can tell. It played when I was presenting it within the app delegate. Just not when I'm trying to present it within its own view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies within the fact, that your `moviePlayerController` is being cleaned up due to ARC.

Try if it helps to introduce a `strong` property for the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I introduced a property that fixed my problem.